# Django: Can't save image from template

Tags: python, html, django

If I try to save image from admin site, it works properly.
But I'm trying to save image from template, and its not working. here is my code

models.py:

```
class About(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profilePicture = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/profile/', default = 'images/useravater.png')
```

views.py:

```
def editProfile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        profilePicture = request.FILES['pp']
        About.objects.filter(user=request.user).update(profilePicture=profilePicture)
    # more code...
```

html:

```
<form style="width: 100%;" action="/editProfile/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
    <input id="inputpp" type="file" accept="image/*" name="pp" title="Select Image">
    <!-- more code -->
</form>
```

after running this code, if i try to print:

```
print(About.objects.get(user=request.user).profilePicture.url)
```

it shows:

```
Not Found: /media/image_name.jpg
```

can you please find my problem?
how do I save image to `/media/images/profile/`?

Comment: Can you show your full `view` of `edit_profile` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to use OneToOneField in your case.

```
models.py:

class About(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='about' on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profilePicture = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/profile/', default = 'images/useravater.png')


views.py:

def editProfile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        profilePicture = request.FILES['pp']
        if request.user.about:
            request.user.about.profilePicture=profilePicture
            request.user.about.save()
        # more code...
```

Comment: This is not helpful. it showing another error: ```'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'save'```

Comment: did you change ForeignKey to OneToOneField? Because if you use ForeignKey and use request.user.about this means it returns RelatedManager

Comment: Lovely. It works. i didn't change ForeignKey to OneToOneField. Thank you.